# How to use a CSS from other page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, velocity

I have this Velocity file, called styles.vm for exemple.

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
       #IF(client == 1)
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client1.css">
       #ELSE IF (client == 2)
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client2.css">
       #ELSE IF (client == 3)
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client3.css">
       #ELSE IF (client == 4)
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client4.css">
       .
       .
       .
       #END
   <HEAD>
</HTML>
```

And I have a bunch of .VMs and .JSPs files, that I need to set their CSS without copy all those conditions in each file again. In short, I want to use the CSS settled in other file, is it possible, doing a include or something like that ?
If necessary I can use JQuery too, because all these files in this project has Jquery imported.

Comment: You should consider string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include a template, for example "styles.vm", in another template, you could do:

```
#parse("/path/to/styles.vm")
```

The #parse script element allows the template designer to import a local file that contains VTL. Velocity will parse the VTL and render the template specified.

[Read more about the #parse script in the Velocity Documentation.](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#parse)